# Way to run the class instance in sequence (typescript nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a typescript class, calling the same function multiple time but it runs in an async way.

I want to run in such a way that when the first call finished, run second and so on... using rxjs or any other way

```
class person extends human{

  async identity(id:any, data: any){
    await writeData(id,data);
  }

}

class human(){
  writeData(id:any, data: any){
    console.log(id,data);
  }
}

person.identity(1,'a');
person.identity(2,'b');
person.identity(3,'c');
person.identity(4,'d');

Output : 

3,'c';
4,'d';
.......
```

expected output should be in sequence

Comment: Your `identity` function's syntax doesn't look right ATM, it must be `async`, I believe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `identity` function `async` so that you can use `await` inside it, and then it'll return a Promise that resolves when it reaches the end - so, just `await` each call of `person.identity`. You should also reference `this.writeData` in order to get to the `human.prototype.writeData` function.

```
class person extends human{
  async identity(id:any, data: any){
    await this.writeData(id,data);
  }
}
```

and

```
(async () => {
  await person.identity(1,'a');
  await person.identity(2,'b');
  await person.identity(3,'c');
  await person.identity(4,'d');
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should:

- use the `async` keyword in any function that use await
- actually `await` any Promise that you want to wait

---

```
class person extends human{

  async identity(id:any, data: any){
    await writeData(id,data);
  }

}

class human(){
  writeData(id:any, data: any){
    console.log(id,data);
  }
}

(async () => {
  await person.identity(1,'a');
  await person.identity(2,'b');
  await person.identity(3,'c');
  await person.identity(4,'d');
}
```